# Bloc State is yielded but UI is not updating

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I'm having an issue using bloc. The bloc state is updating but it seems to be no effect on UI. I have reproduced the issue using an example app. The issue is removing an item from the list page does not change is color back to deselected state. Actually what happens is When you select an item on home page the cart button appears and on no items selected state it disappears. So when you selected an item on homepage the cart button appears. When you click on the button you're navigated to another page i.e. ListPage where you can see the list of all selected items and a remove button corresponding to every item. When you remove an item it gets removed from ListPage but still it's color is Red i.e. selected on HomePage. I have to click again to change the color although it was deselected i.e. (item.active = false) on removing it from the ListPage. Just the color stays the same, it's not getting updated. The code files are given below:

item_bloc.dart

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:demo/bloc/cart/cart_bloc.dart';
import 'package:demo/item_model.dart';
import 'package:demo/repository.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

part 'items_event.dart';
part 'items_state.dart';

class ItemsBloc extends Bloc<ItemsEvent, ItemsState> {
  final ItemRepository itemRepository;
  final CartBloc cartBloc;

  ItemsBloc({
    @required this.itemRepository,
    @required this.cartBloc,
  }) : super(ItemsLoading());

  @override
  Stream<ItemsState> mapEventToState(
    ItemsEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is GetItems) {
      yield* _mapGetItemsToState(event);
    } else if (event is UpdateItem) {
      yield* _mapUpdateItemToState(event);
    }
  }

  Stream<ItemsState> _mapGetItemsToState(GetItems event) async* {
    yield ItemsLoading();
    try {
      final _items = await itemRepository.loadItems();
      yield ItemsLoaded(items: _items);
      print('Yielded');
    } catch (_) {
      yield ItemsFailure();
    }
  }

  Stream<ItemsState> _mapUpdateItemToState(UpdateItem event) async* {
    try {
      _updateRepositoryItems(event.item);
      if (event.item.active) {
        cartBloc.add(ShowItems());
      } else {
        cartBloc.add(RemoveItem(itemId: event.item.id));
      }
      yield* _mapGetItemsToState(GetItems());
    } catch (_) {
      yield ItemsFailure();
    }
  }

  Item _updateRepositoryItems(Item item) => itemRepository.setItem = item;
}
```

cart_bloc.dart

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:demo/item_data_model.dart';
import 'package:demo/repository.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

part 'cart_event.dart';
part 'cart_state.dart';

class CartBloc extends Bloc<CartEvent, CartState> {
  final ItemRepository itemRepository;

  CartBloc({@required this.itemRepository}) : super(CartLoading());

  @override
  Stream<CartState> mapEventToState(
    CartEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is ShowItems) {
      yield* _mapShowItemsToState(event);
    } else if (event is RemoveItem) {
      yield* _mapRemoveItemToState(event);
    }
  }

  Stream<CartState> _mapShowItemsToState(ShowItems event) async* {
    try {
      final _selectedItems = await itemRepository.getSelectedItems;

      if (_selectedItems.isNotEmpty) {
        final data = ItemData(items: _selectedItems);

        yield CartLoaded(itemData: data);
      } else {
        yield CartLoading();
      }
    } catch (_) {
      yield CartFailure();
    }
  }

  Stream<CartState> _mapRemoveItemToState(RemoveItem event) async* {
    try {
      final _selectedSounds = await itemRepository.getSelectedItems;

      if (_selectedSounds.isEmpty) {
        yield CartLoading();
      } else {
        yield* _mapShowItemsToState(ShowItems());
      }
    } catch (_) {
      yield CartFailure();
    }
  }
}
```

homepage.dart

```
import 'package:demo/bloc/cart/cart_bloc.dart';
import 'package:demo/bloc/items/items_bloc.dart';
import 'package:demo/item_tile.dart';
import 'package:demo/list_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Home Page"),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: BlocBuilder<ItemsBloc, ItemsState>(
                  // ignore: missing_return
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    if (state is ItemsLoading) {
                      return Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    } else if (state is ItemsLoaded) {
                      print('Items Loaded');
                      return GridView.count(
                        crossAxisCount: 3,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 20.0,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 20.0,
                        childAspectRatio: 0.6,
                        children: [
                          for (var item in state.items) ItemTile(item: item),
                        ],
                      );
                    } else if (state is ItemsFailure) {
                      return Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'Unexpected Failure, Cannot Load Items',
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: CartButton(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CartButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<CartBloc, CartState>(
      // ignore: missing_return
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is CartLoading) {
          return SizedBox.shrink();
        } else if (state is CartLoaded) {
          print('Cart Loaded');
          return TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                  return ListPage(
                    items: state.itemData.items,
                  );
                }),
              );
            },
            child: Text('Go To Cart'),
          );
        } else if (state is CartFailure) {
          return Center(
            child: Text(
              'Unexpected Failure, Cannot Load Cart',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

item_tile.dart

```
import 'package:demo/bloc/items/items_bloc.dart';
import 'package:demo/get_it.dart';
import 'package:demo/item_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ItemTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final Item item;

  const ItemTile({Key key, this.item}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _ItemTileState createState() => _ItemTileState();
}

class _ItemTileState extends State<ItemTile> {
  bool active;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    active = widget.item.active;
  }

  void _onItemTap() {
    setState(() {
      active = !active;
    });

    getIt<ItemsBloc>()
        .add(UpdateItem(item: widget.item.copyWith(active: active)));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(widget.item.title),
      tileColor: active ? Colors.redAccent : Colors.blueAccent,
      onTap: () {
        _onItemTap();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

item_page.dart

```
import 'package:demo/bloc/items/items_bloc.dart';
import 'package:demo/get_it.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'item_model.dart';

class ListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Item> items;

  const ListPage({Key key, this.items}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _PlayerScreenState createState() => _PlayerScreenState();
}

class _PlayerScreenState extends State<ListPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            'Cart List Page',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.separated(
                  itemCount: widget.items.length,
                  separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                      Divider(),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      trailing: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.close_rounded,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          getIt<ItemsBloc>().add(UpdateItem(
                            item: widget.items.elementAt(index).copyWith(
                                active: !widget.items.elementAt(index).active),
                          ));

                          setState(() {
                            widget.items.removeAt(index);
                          });
                          if (widget.items.isEmpty) {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                      title: Text(
                        widget.items.elementAt(index).title,
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

get_it.dart

```
import 'package:demo/bloc/cart/cart_bloc.dart';
import 'package:demo/bloc/items/items_bloc.dart';
import 'package:demo/repository.dart';
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';

final getIt = GetIt.instance;

Future<void> init() async {
  // Bloc

  getIt.registerLazySingleton<CartBloc>(() => CartBloc(itemRepository: getIt()));

  getIt.registerFactory(() => ItemsBloc(
        itemRepository: getIt(),
        cartBloc: getIt(),
      ));

  // Repository
  getIt.registerSingleton<ItemRepository>(ItemRepository());
}
```

main.dart

```
import 'package:demo/bloc/cart/cart_bloc.dart';
import 'package:demo/bloc/items/items_bloc.dart';
import 'package:demo/get_it.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

import 'get_it.dart' as di;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'home_page.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  di.init();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => getIt<ItemsBloc>()..add(GetItems()),
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => getIt<CartBloc>(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Down Here are the images of the issue:

[image: Home Page]

[image: List Page]

Comment: Do you see your `print('Items Loaded');` statement in the console when you're expecting the color to change? If not, then the `BlocBuilder` is not rebuilding when you want it to. Once your `ItemsLoaded` state is yielded, it should rebuild the whole list of tiles with the updated colors.

Comment: When the app starts it shows in the console as (I/flutter ( 4923): Items Loaded) and when you select an item it shows (I/flutter ( 4923): Cart Loaded). Yes as you told when we remove items from the ItemPage it is not showing Items Loaded. And that is the problem.

Comment: I added a line after yield ItemsLoaded in _mapGetItemsToState as print('Yielded') in the Items_bloc file. It is printing that line on removing the item. So the state is yielded but somehow i think bloc is treating the new state with updated items as the previous one and that's why the BlocBuilder function is not called again. I got no idea how to fix this issue. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so based on the comments, that indicates that you're already in an `ItemsLoaded` state when removing the item. Since it's not a new state, then a rebuild is not triggered. So it's behaving as expected. Looks like you need to rethink how you do this, perhaps by yielding an `ItemsUpdated` state before then yielding the `ItemsLoaded` state.

Comment: I thought I should create a new State i.e. ItemsUpdated, but it would also create the same problem as the list of updated items would be treated as same. But as you say yielding ItemsUpdated state before ItemsLoaded would work then why yielding ItemsLoading before ItemsLoaded is not working. Both the cases are same though.